# Ejecutar script Python desde código Java

Tags: java, python

Estoy llamando a un script Python desde mi código Java sin obtener ningún resultado:

```
String cmdStr =
      "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda2\\python.exe
       C:\\dicom\\write_pydicom_cmd.py
      -ip C:\\Reconstructed\\Test\\2019-12-11_16-13-52\\MERGEDBEDS_1FRAME.img
      -hp C:\\Reconstructed\\Test\\2019-12-11_16-13-52\\MERGEDBEDS_1FRAME.hdr
      -op C:\\Reconstructed\\Test\\2019-12-11_16-13-52\\MERGEDBEDS";

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdStr);
```

Si abro la consola y llamo a ese mismo script sí que funciona.

¿Por qué no funciona desde mi código Java?

Comment: Quieres que te muestre algun `print`??? o abres alguna ventana con ese script

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres es imprimir el resultado de un `print()` que está en tu script de python prueba imprimiendo el resultado de la siguiente forma:

```
String command = "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda2\\python.exe C:\\dicom\\write_pydicom_cmd.py -ip C:\\Reconstructed\\Test\\2019-12-11_16-13-52\\MERGEDBEDS_1FRAME.img -hp C:\\Reconstructed\\Test\\2019-12-11_16-13-52\\MERGEDBEDS_1FRAME.hdr -op C:\\Reconstructed\\Test\\2019-12-11_16-13-52\\MERGEDBEDS";
Scanner scan = new Scanner(Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command).getInputStream());
String res = scan.hasNext() ? scan.next() : "";
System.out.println(res);
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos ;)

Comment: Hola Israel-ICM, veo que propones muchas ediciones en las publicaciones. Algunas me chirrían un poco, ¿te importaría leer este debate? [¿Tiene sentido editar una publicación marcando `palabras` como código?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4471/83) Para ver si unificamos criterios. ¡Gracias y buen trabajo!

Comment: Claro lo revisare, gracias por la info, aunque si me di cuenta ya que habia leido acerca de marcar las clases y las variables como codigo intentare mejorar gracias. ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias a ti, Israel, por mostrarte abierto a debatirlo!